# Access Database c# query Problems

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Here is the background of my problem: I have a combobox that when users start typing, it should retrieve suggested items from a column in database table. The user starts inputing name and the program should suggest names by looking at both first and last names (database has separate tables for both )

Here is the code that I had:

```
        try{
            String temp = nameCBox.Text;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection namesSuggestion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=C:\\LogEntry\\LogEntry.accdb; Persist Security Info = False;");
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            conn.Open();
            String text2send = "Select Name from [Teachers] where FName like '" + temp + "' OR LName like '" + temp + "' Group by [Name]";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(text2send, conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    namesSuggestion.Add(reader["temp"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            nameCBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesSuggestion;

            conn.Close();
            }
```

errors: 
1) I see no suggestions in the combo box
2) When I type in the combo box, it highlights the text and when I type something else again, it will write on the previous typed character.

Please Help
desktopmaker

Comment: First Suggestion: use parameterized queries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Like operator, try to make the input between look like this : `%input%`
To get something like :

Take a look at [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php), it may help

```
var sql = String.Format("Select Name from [Teachers] WHERE FName Like '%{0}%' OR LName Like '%{0}%'", temp);
```

Other points may be helpful about your current code :

- Use the `using` statement in your code, it dispose the resources, and for the Connection, it close it.

  ```
  using(var conn = new OleDbConnection("ConnectionStrong"))
  {
      //code
  }
  ```
- The best, is to use a parameterized query [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: So, something like this ?'String text2send = String.Format("SELECT Name FROM [Teachers] WHERE FName like %{0}% OR LName like %{0}% Group by [Name]",temp, temp);'

Comment: No, no need to put temp tow times, I've edited my post to have your entire Sql to send

Comment: SidAhmed, I get a syntax error saying "Syntax error in query expression 'FName Like %s% OR LName %s%'.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the '' arround the %{0}% to be '%{0}%', post edited

Comment: should be single quotes around the like argument "Fname Like '%{0}%'".

Comment: Now, the syntax error is gone, but it doesn't retrieve anything from the database. (it didnt do that before also)

Comment: What's the generated Sql ? did you try to execute it in the Access ?

Comment: Just tried to run it in access and here is the problem. when the user starts typing in a value for name, say "jo" then the combobox should suggest names that start with 'jo'like it should give a list (john,josh,jonathan,...) but my query is looking for exact name 'jo'

Comment: Are you sure you did not forgot the % sign ? By adding the '%{0}%', it should search for items CINTAINING the input, to get the BEGIN WITH items use : '{0}%'

Comment: yeah, I am using those. right now, that string looks like this: var sql = String.Format("Select [Name] from [Teachers] WHERE FName Like '%{0}%' OR LName Like  '%{0}%'", temp);

Comment: This code should work fine, just checking, does your databse realy contains data, what do you have if you execute "select [name] from [teachers]" in your access ?

Comment: Access is non-standard try * instead of %

Answer (score 0):

Erm

What's this doing

```
namesSuggestion.Add(reader["temp"].ToString());
```

reader is returning a column called Name..

I wouldunless the user is typing it in expect the search string to contain a wild card.

E.g. `Like 'John%'`, or `Like '%Smith'` in standard sql, access uses * instead of % I seem to remember.

Oh and presumably you aren't worried about sql injection attacks??

Comment: I want the reader to put all the retrieved values from the column Name in namesSuggestion.

this is my first time doing access database, I am learning as I go. I have used parameter query when adding values into the database but I didnt think about it when I am doing data retrieval.

Comment: it's clearly better using parameterized queries. do yourself a favor and learn how to use them. this prevent your application from sql injection attacks.